# How to write several RichTextBox Contents into one RTF file preserving font formats of each RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf, streamwriter

I have a Winforms project where I can write text into a RichTextBox, and some controls to set the font formats of the written text. I am able to save and append text to RTF file, but I'm having a problem of preserving **font formats** of each RichTextBox. Any Help?

CODE:

```
RichTextBox r1 = new RichTextBox();
RichTextBox r2 = new RichTextBox();
string nickName = "Test: ";
string message = "Hi this is a test message";
r1.Text = nickName;
r1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

r2.Text = message;
r2.ForeColor = Color.Black;

string path = @"d:\Test.rtf";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(r1.Rtf);
        sw.WriteLine(r2.Rtf);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(r1.Rtf);
        sw.WriteLine(r2.Rtf);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you open your `Test.rtf` file (such as with `WordPad`) it doesn't show the correct `ForeColor`? Any more details?

Comment: yes, when I open the test.rtf, in this case, either all the text is printed in 1 format, or only the content of the first RichTextBox is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by merging all the content into the same `RichTextBox`. Sample:

```
r1.Text = r1.Text + Environment.NewLine;
r1.SelectAll();
r1.Copy();
r2.Paste();

r2.SaveFile(path);
```

This approach works fine with `StreamWriter` as you were using it. On the other hand, why not using a simpler/specifically-designed-for-this-purpose method (`SaveFile`)? If you don't want to replace the contents in `r2`, you can just rely on a temporary `RichTextBox`:

```
 r1.Text = r1.Text + Environment.NewLine;
 r1.SelectAll();
 r1.Copy();
 RichTextBox temp = new RichTextBox();
 temp.Paste();
 r2.SelectAll();
 r2.Copy();
 temp.Paste();

 temp.SaveFile(path);
```

NOTE: there might be problems when using `StreamWriter` (to append, for example). Bear in mind that RTF is a special format which requires a special treatment: perform any modification from the `RichTextBox` control (add, remove, edit, etc. text/format) and rely on the methods `LoadFile` and `SaveFile`, rather than in the ones for TXT files (i.e., StreamReader/StreamWriter).

Comment: Everything works, but I am not able to append to the same file extra text... how can I do that?

Comment: I mean my method above while using streamWriter to append: works fine with plain text, but does not work with RichTextBox: 
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, **FileMode.Append,** FileAccess.Write))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        **sw.WriteLine(r2.Rtf);**
        sw.Close();
    } **ANY SUGGESTIONS?**

Comment: @samerAzar you are right, there are problems while appending it. Bear in mind that rtf is an "special format" (like MS Office Word). I tested the StreamWriter and it worked and that's why I assumed that you can use it without any restriction, but apparently this is not the case. The best way to avoid problems is rely on the specific methods, in this case: SaveFile and LoadFile (ignore streamWriter). If you want to override the 1.rtf, use richTextBox.LoadFile("1.rtf") add anything you want to richTextBox and save it with richTextBox.SaveFile("1.rtf").

Comment: @samerAzar I have added a clarification to my answer saying basically the same than in my previous comment: better don't treat RTFs as TXTs (= rely on StreamWriter/StreamReader as less as possible).